# Unity Leap Motion Detecting Finger collision with other fingers/palm

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I am new to using Unity and Leap motion.

I have copied over the HandModels and LeapHandController from the Unity Asset Pack Desktop demo.

I am trying to activate a function to instantiate an object when the thumbs bone 3 collides with any other part of the hand and i did this by creating a simple script with an `OnCollisionEnter` function and attaching it to the Bone3 of Thumb but it doesn't seem to activate when the thumb collides with any other part of the hand/finger that it is a child of. If i add a cube to the scene and give it a rigidbody it will successfully trigger the `onCollisionEnter` of the thumb (shown via a print statement), but it wont trigger `oncollisionEnter` with any of its siblings in the hand model.

I am unsure how the standard method for detecting finger collisions with other objects using Leap Motion and Unity is, but it doesn't seem to follow the standard Unity Collision system. Is there another way i should be detecting it? It would be helpful if i could detect collisions of a hands child bones, but right now it seems i have to signal to the hand manually that a child bone has collided.

Comment: @Hellium these aren't up to date, the Leap API changed within the last month and it has some pretty significant new features

Comment: @Hellium None of those links answer the asker's question, or even discuss trying to do what the asker is trying to do. The asker is trying to detect a hands collisions with itself, e.g., one finger to another finger on the same hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've copied over HandModels from a Desktop demo, the physical hand you're working with is probably a `RigidRoundHand` -- you can confirm this by checking what objects are underneath your HandModels object.

If it is indeed the RigidRoundHand, or otherwise using the RigidHand script to generate the colliders of the hand, the issue you're observing comes from the fact that **a hand is all one rigidbody**, so the reason you aren't seeing OnCollisionEnter is because the rigidbody doesn't receive OnCollisionEnter when it "collides" with itself.

To accomplish what you're trying to do, instead of relying on the default colliders of the hand, you should place specific Rigidbody + Collider objects (such as the default Unity Cube) on the specific locations of the hand you'd like to detect collision against. I would recommend using the [Attachment Hands](https://github.com/leapmotion/UnityModules/wiki/Core#attachment-hands) made available in a recent release to do this: It will make it easy for you to place individual Rigidbodies on specific joints in the hand, such as the tip of the thumb, and the other locations you're trying to collide against.

Make sure you're using [the latest version of the Leap Motion Unity SDK](https://developer.leapmotion.com/unity/#116), then check out the example scene in `LeapMotion/Core/Examples/Attachment Hands/` in your Assets folder. Make sure you have a Kinematic Rigidbody Collider (a SphereCollider is a good choice) under the Attachment Hand's thumb, and add some script like:

```cs
public class ThumbCollisionDetector : MonoBehaviour {
  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision c) {
    if (c.gameObject.GetComponent<MiddleFingerIdentifier>() != null) {
      Debug.Log("The thumb collided with the middle finger identifier!");
    }
  }
}
```

In the above example, we're looking for a "MiddleFingertipIdentifier" script in the collision, so we need to make sure there's an object with a Kinematic Rigidbody and a Collider *attached* (via Attachment Hands) to the tip bone of the middle finger -- the identifier script doesn't even have to contain anything, it just has to be there:

```
public class MiddleFingertipIdentifier : MonoBehaviour { }
```

That logic should get you started detecting internal hand intersections.

Comment: thanks for the advice, this helps a lot. The only issue i am having right now is that the AttachementHand example renders the hands weirdly and buggy. With the RigidRoundHand example that i was using (you guessed correctly) it rendered the hands very nicely and without sudden jumping/glitching. But in attachement hands it seems to jump all over the place and not be as smooth and precise as the RigidRoundHands(Desktop) example.

Comment: I removed the camera component fro the leap controller and attached a new camera to the hands and offset it a bit then i removed the AttachemenHands as a child from the leap headmounted rig and put it along and then raised the hands with respect to the leap controller and it seems to help a lot.

Comment: Curious... Unfortunately, there are far too many reasons that could be happening for me to debug what you're describing without a much more detailed picture of your setup. If you have a scene where your RigidRoundHands are rendering "correctly", you should try adding an Attachment Hands script in the same place you see it in the Attachment Hands scene. Then you can use its inspector to add Transforms for attachment points you're interested in using (e.g. the Thumb Tip). It uses the same hand data as all the other components, so it should still "just work" in your other scene.

Comment: Ah, do be aware that the Attachment Hands demo was designed for VR, so if you're using it in a Desktop context, it may look weird. You shouldn't be using the LMHeadMountedRig if you're planning on using the Leap Motion on a desk top.

Comment: do you happen to know a way for a parent to detect collisions of its children. I believe it would be better architecture for the hand to detect if two specific fingers collide instead of checking if any collisions occur and then sorting out what happened.

Comment: "A parent detecting collisions of its children" is not your issue. Your issue is that you're trying to detect specific collider-pair collisions inside a compound-collider Rigidbody, which is what RigidRoundHand is: it's one rigidbody with multiple colliders. You need to be detecting collisions _between separate Rigidbodies_, not collisions "inside" a single Rigidbody. My answer solves your problem by allowing you to assign different Rigidbodies to each finger, which will cause OnCollisionEnter in the way you are expecting.

Comment: i may still be confused, i added a cube with rigid body and box collider under the thumb tip (and all other finger areas) and then added your script but without the if statement (so it logs on all collisions no matter the other finger) but it still isn't detecting the collision.

Comment: i finally solved it, i was an idiot and forgot to add a rigidbody to the OTHER fingers. Because a collision only can occur between two rigid bodies. Now everything works great! thanks so much for your help!